# Django: Intermittent 'template not found'

Tags: django, templates, nginx, uwsgi, centos7

I have an app that is deployed at 15 sites and has been running for 6 years. All these deployments are with django 1.5, python 2.6, CentOS6, and apache, and they all work perfectly. I just deployed the app at a new site, but this one is django 1.9, python 2.7, CentOS7, and nginx/uwsgi. Only at this site we are seeing intermittent 'template not found' errors. A refresh of the page always works. It happens with different templates, and there are no errors in any of the logs (except for the template not found error). I've checked the system logs, the nginx logs, the uwsgi logs and the django logs.

Anyone know why this would be happening, and/or how I can debug it further?

One thing I noticed, and this may be normal, but I don't know as I've never encountered this error before, is that in the template not found error when it lists the directories it searched, they all are in /tmp. For example if the template is in /usr/local/foo/bar/templates/baz/template.html the search path in the error will have /tmp/foo/bar/templates/baz. Is that any indication of a problem?

More info as requested:

Error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /report/CDSEM/WaferToWafer/

WaferToWafer/view.html
```

Template search:

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /usr/local/motor/motor/ui/templates/WaferToWafer/view.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/WaferToWafer/view.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/WaferToWafer/view.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /tmp/core/alerts/templates/WaferToWafer/view.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /tmp/core/reports/templates/WaferToWafer/view.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /tmp/app/cdsem/templates/WaferToWafer/view.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /tmp/app/semvision/templates/WaferToWafer/view.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /tmp/app/developer/templates/WaferToWafer/view.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /tmp/ui/templates/WaferToWafer/view.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /tmp/configuration/templates/WaferToWafer/view.html (Source does not exist)
```

TEMPLATES from settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'motor/ui/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'context_processors.config',
                'ui.context_processors.navigation',
                'core.appmngr.context_processor',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

The template it is searching for does exist at `/usr/local/motor/motor/app/cdsem/templates/WaferToWafer/view.html`

When I get the error if I refresh the page it works.

Comment: Could you show the full list of directories searched when there is an error? Also your `TEMPLATES` setting (or the equivalent old-style templates settings)?

Comment: A lot has changed between 1.5 and 1.9 so it would be hard to expect it just just work. Either way, try to create a [mcve].

Comment: I don't have remote access to this site, so I will have to go on site and try and recreate the error. That will not be until next week. I know a lot has changed from 1.5 to 1.9 as I had to make a lot of code changes to update the version. It didn't 'just work' - a lot of time when into it. And a lot of testing was done, as well as running a regression test suite I have. Creating a minimal example will be very hard as it's a very large app and this error is very intermittent.

Comment: After you provide more information make sure you add a comment here mentioning @AntonisChristofides.

Comment: @AntonisChristofides I have updated the question with the details you requested. Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: Very often the problem of intermittent failure is because uwsgi (or gunicorn, or mod_wsgi) uses many processes, and some of them use another installation of the program. This can occur when you make a change and forget to restart. Then older processes use the old code, but they eventually die and are replaced by new ones, which use the new code. Try stopping uwsgi, verify the site isn't running at all, then restart uwsgi (or restart the server).

Comment: BTW, why did you switch from apache to nginx?

Comment: No, no code is changing. I did try restarting uwsgi when I first saw the error. We switched because we felt nginx was more state of the art. Why do the template search paths look in /tmp and not the actual dir with the templates? This has started happing more frequently. Any thoughts on how I can fix it?

Comment: No ideas. It's probably one of those things that's in front of your eyes but you can't see it. Anyway, I don't believe it's normal for it to search for templates in `/tmp`. For some reason it sometimes thinks your Django apps are installed in `/tmp` when in fact they are in `/usr/local/motor/motor`.

Answer (score 0):

I 'fixed' this by explicitly listing the template dirs in the TEMPLATES dict. Still don't know why I had to do this at just this one site.